# Cannot find SPI device

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

I am using Raspberry Pi Zero W with a PiTFT. I have managed to put an image on the screen as explained here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi

After that, I've tried to use the Adafruit Python ILI9341 as explained here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ILI9341

There is no problem at the instalation, BUT when I've tried to execute an example it said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 41, in <module>
    disp = TFT.ILI9341(DC, rst=RST, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT,             
SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=64000000))
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/SPI.py", line 42,     
in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The tree hierarchy is missing starting with the 'egg' folder.
I've tried to manually create it, but I got the same error.

My instincts were that there is a problem with the SPI connection or the spidev kernel module.
There is no spi device in the /dev/ directory.
In the /boot/config.txt the spi is on, I've enabled it in the raspi-config menu. I've also checked and it is not even blacklisted.

I am using a pi image, not a PiTFT image.
Please HELP!